# Dynamically Add Rows in Knockoutjs

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am using knockoutjs and i have 2 column Qualification List and Marks . After clicking at Add button i want to generate new rows and after click on submit button it need to show the chosen Qualification List and my marks.

I have code here: https://jsfiddle.net/wg3t172b/

```
self.QualificationLists = ko.observableArray([
      { QualName: 'Master', QualId: '0' },
      { QualName: 'Bachelor', QualId: '1' },
      { QualName: 'CA', QualId: '2' },
      { QualName: 'School Leaving', QualId: '3' }
  ]);
  self.addQualification = function () {
      self.Qualifications.push({
         QualList: "",
         QualificationLists: "",
         Marks: "",
         selectedQualName: "",
    });
  };

  self.removeQual = function (Qualification) {
     self.Qualifications.remove(Qualification);
 };

  self.save = function (form) {
     console.log(self.Qualifications());
  };
};

var viewModel = new QualificationModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

when i console Qualification it shows only Marks but my expected result should be QualId QualName and Marks in one array.

Comment: You have to add $parent to your html bindings for the selects (options binding) since ur inside a foreach, so you are using the wrong scope when targeting the qualificationlist

Comment: Can you please help me . I am new in knockout js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the scope for your select. Use `$parent` to move one scope out from the context inside your `foreach` binding.

```
<select data-bind="options: $parent.QualificationLists, optionsText:'QualName',
```

Edit: To clarify. When you are inside a `foreach` binding, your current scope is the current item in the iteration. Because your `QualificationLists` is directly on your viewmodel, and not actually on the items you are looping over, you have to call it from the parent context

Comment: No worries mate. If my answer resolved your issue, could you please mark it as the answer?